# Rotation changing height of image

Tags: html, css

I have code which rotates the image 360 degrees infinitely. All things seem fine but the rotation of the image is causing the image to resize i.e., the height of page with increasing and decreasing. I'm not getting why is it happening. The fluctuation of scroll bar shows it.

I've attached a sample snippet which illustrates my problem.

```css
.logo-circle img {
    -webkit-animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
    animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    left: 27.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
 
@keyframes spin1 {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-circle img-responsive">
   <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/09/Circle_Logo.svg/1024px-Circle_Logo.svg.png" width = "45%"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Because a `transform` doesn't change the size of the image at all. So when you rotate it, the actual **effective** height of the object changes due to Pythagoras. give the element a bg color...you can see,

Comment: add `border: solid 1px black` to `.logo-circle img` to illustrate the behaviour and how Chiller answers solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not resizing, but when it rotates it takes a larger space because of the corners

[image]

You can resolve that by adding `overflow:hidden` to body

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.logo-circle {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.logo-circle img {
  -webkit-animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
  animation: spin1 100s infinite linear;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 27.5%;
  max-height: 95%;
  width: auto;
}

@keyframes spin1 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-circle img-responsive">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/0/09/Circle_Logo.svg/1024px-Circle_Logo.svg.png" width="45%">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but adding overflow:hidden to body won't effect other elements on the page?

Comment: @SnehaBharti it will affect the other elements .. if you have other elements than you should apply it on the image container `.logo-circle img-responsive`

Comment: @SnehaBharti i edited my answer .. i changed the css a little bit take a look

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's about `img-responsive` class from Bootstrap? ... it's use "`max-width and height:auto;`" So if Your image is not a square, it can be resized.